# Making a timer and trying to convert UInt64 to a valid time string

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a timer class which utilizes start/stop functionality, and i utilize an inhouse call `GetCurrentTimeAsUnixMillis()` which returns a *UInt64*.

My goal is to create a string in the format of: `HH:MM:SS:mmm`

The naive approach I was thinking was:

```
auto start = GetCurrentTimeAsUnixMillis();
auto end   = GetCurrentTimeAsUnixMillis();
auto value = end - start;  //gets the difference between start and stop.
auto ms = 1;
auto s = ms*1000;
auto m = s*60;
auto h = m*60;

Utf8String out("");
out   += value/h + ":";
value -= value/h;
out   += value/m + ":";
value -= value/m;
out   += value/s + ":";
value -= value/s;
out   += value;

return out;
```

I just think this is too much computation and therefore the wrong answer.

Comment: Let's say there's a library call you could make instead, do you think that call wouldn't need to do all the same math?  You should make `ms`, `s`, etc. constants, they aren't going to change.  You probably want to think about how you do the formatting a bit though if you want something like `01:02:03:004`.  Your code doesn't add leading zeroes.

Comment: Yes and no.  I know that it would call similar code, but when you deal with libraries, especially those that are std, it would be optimized and possibly resolve with bitshifting vs integer division.

Comment: Do you mean you're getting the wrong result, or that you feel there's a more efficient way to do this? Depending on what `Utf8String` is, maybe you could preallocate enough room to contain the output string? If that's not possible, declaring a local buffer, using `snprintf` to print all the values into it, and then constructing a `Utf8String` from the buffer might be more efficient.

Comment: all the division and string appends i felt were not clean, nor really efficient.  Ideally, i would like to have something better in terms of efficiency.

Comment: @RetiredNinja - `s`, `m`, etc are constants. The compiler is not that stupid and can optimise that out of the equation

Comment: @Praetorian Thats true.  I think that since it would at most be:  HH:MM:SS:mmm, that could be with some sort of `sprintf` or `snprintf`.

Comment: What is wrong, what do you expect instead?

Comment: I see:  6 divisions, and 4 string appends, utilizing the space of 2 variables, out and value.  I was not sure if there would be a way to cut down on the calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't claim this is definitely faster, but it is more modern I suppose.

```
auto elapsed = std::chrono::milliseconds{end-start};

auto h  = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::hours>(elapsed);
auto m  = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::minutes>(elapsed);
auto s  = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(elapsed);
auto ms = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(elapsed);

ms -= s;
s  -= m;
m  -= h;

// format using h.count(), m.count(), s.count(), ms.count()
```

Comment: Dave, i keep getting a:  `std::chrono` has not been declared.  Thoughts?

Comment: @Fallenreaper `#include <chrono>`

Answer (score 0):

It is tough to outsmart the optimizer. I would probably cascade out modulo and division, and attempt to do the formatting in a single call, but I am not sure if that is possible with a `Utf8String`, as I am unfamiliar with it.

```
// start with millisecond
auto ms = value % 1000;
value /= 1000;
// now second
auto s = value % 60;
value /= 60;
// now minute
auto m = value % 60;
value /= 60;
// now hour
auto h = value;
//... formatting the output left as an exercise ...
```